# How to insert new line to Microsoft Bot Framework Thumbnail card subtitle

Tags: botframework

I am following this document to create a thumbnail card using Microsoft Botframework: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tsmatsuz/2016/08/31/microsoft-bot-framework-messages-howto-image-html-card-button-etc/

I want the subtitle to have multiple lines of text. I tried to insert \n, \n\n, \r\n. But the final result on Microsoft Team looks the same.

What's the best way to achieve this?

BTW. I am using the Bot Framework C# SDK V3.3.3

Comment: I've had success with adding <br /> to many field types in MSTeams. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only there is no way to insert line breaks, it is nearly useless because the subtitle is limited to 60 characters.

You could possibly override this by creating your own class extending HeroCard or by modifying `ChannelData`.

Alternatively, just try some nice character like · to separate your items like email, phone etc.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know the character limitation. But for what I need (displaying an email address and a phone number), that should be enough.

Comment: I'd use the · character to separate the values

Answer (score 1):

MS Teams HeroCards do not allow for carriage returns in the Title and SubTitle fields.

Comment: What about the "Text" field of the Hero or Thumbnail card?

Comment: It doesn't look like it supports character returns in the text field either